I am experiencing ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock'
I am using MAC apple silicon, on Sonama 14.4.1
I came across this error while following a tutorial installing MySQL server. I searched around for solutions but none of them seem to work. I get this error when I go into the terminal and type my root password after using the command mysql -u root -p
Other solutions involved going into system settings and clicking "start MySQL server" as well as "initialize database" - I noticed here, that the active instance would only turn green for a couple seconds before going back to red.
Any suggestions would be appreciated, as I am unable to progress through the tutorial.
